# Nginx server not working in centos 7

Tags: php, linux, nginx, server

I have installed Nginx server in Cent OS 7, After installed it was opened by giving

```
sudo systemctl start nginx.service
```

command. I have to run **.php** file,so I have modified the file -> **nginx.conf** .
I have added the following

```
     location / {
       root /usr/share/nginx/html;
       index index.php index.htm index.html;
     }

     location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
      fastcgi_index  index.php;
      fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /usr/share/nginx/html$fastcgi_script_name;
      include        fastcgi_params;
     }
```

in to the file -> **nginx.conf**.
Then I start the server again through command ->

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx.service
```

But it's giving the error->

> Job for nginx.service failed. See 'systemctl status nginx.service' and
>   'journalctl -xn' for details.

How can I solve it?

Comment: try checking another process is not running on the same port..

Comment: How about running 'systemctl status nginx' and seeing what the error is? Then we can help.